# Output $action in a INSERT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

How do I output `$action` here for "INSERT"?

```
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (Id int, FirstName nvarchar(50), City nvarchar(50))

INSERT @OutputTbl (Id, FirstName, City)
OUTPUT $ACTION
VALUES
(1,'John','Jackson')

SELECT * FROM @OutputTbl
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Invalid column name '$ACTION'.

> Completion time: 2023-03-29T14:51:33.7353021-04:00

Comment: `OUTPUT 'INSERT'`? An `INSERT` can't do any else other than *insert*.

Comment: I guess checking the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) would clarify i.e. `$action` is for the `merge` statement only.

Comment: If you're doing an INSERT, you already know the action?

Comment: As Dale K suggested, from [`OUTPUT Clause`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments): "$action
Is available only for the MERGE statement." Not a lot of wiggle room on that one.

Comment: @ThomA In the interests of being idiotic: could always do `MERGE @OutputTbl USING (VALUES (1, 'John', 'Jackson')) v(Id, FirstName, City) ON 1=0 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id, FirstName, City) VALUES (Id, FirstName, City) OUTPUT $ACTION;` obviously completely pointless

Comment: The only time I can think to use a `MERGE` like that would be when you want columns that weren't inserted in the `OUTPUT`, as `MERGE` can reference those columns, while an `INSERT` can't, @Charlieface . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bs8XOcCQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Dale K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127428/dale-k) has mentioned, and as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), `$action` is specific to `MERGE` as a `MERGE` can `INSERT`, `UPDATE` *and* `DELETE`.

> $action
> Is available only for the MERGE statement. Specifies a column of type **nvarchar(10)** in the OUTPUT clause in a MERGE statement that returns one of three values for each row: 'INSERT', 'UPDATE', or 'DELETE', according to the action that was performed on that row.

On the other hand, an `INSERT` can only do *one* thing; `INSERT`. So, just return that as a literal as you *know* what the action is:

```sql
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (Id int,
                          FirstName nvarchar(50),
                          City nvarchar(50));

INSERT @OutputTbl (Id, FirstName, City)
OUTPUT N'INSERT'
VALUES (1,'John','Jackson');

SELECT *
FROM @OutputTbl;
```